# Does the BizTalk 2010 BtsAsmExt.dll work with Server 2008 R2?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Does the BizTalk 2010 BtsAsmExt.dll work with Server 2008 R2?

Followed the instructions at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560741.aspx) but the screen shots look to be Windows XP, as it talking about *"My Computer"*

The install by `regsvr32 BtsAsmExt.dll` worked Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.  While BTAV is still shipped, it suffers from two significant deficiencies:

1. It is not supported on 64-bit systems.
2. It does not support the .Net 4.0 GAC.

BizTalk Server 2010 is .Net 4.0 based so because of item 2, any BizTalk 2010 Assemblies you build/deploy would not be visible to BTAV.

Comment: Blast, it looked like a nice tool